# GoogleWebmaster Tools render advertisement on my website

Tags: optimization, google-search-console, ads

so I have finally designed a website and have currently hosted it on 000webhost for free. I wanted to optimize this website using Google Webmaster Tools, but I face a problem when it comes to the Data Highlighting section. This is because Google renders my website with a popup advertisement.

I have tried numerous ways to rid of this advertisement so that Google will not render it, but have failed. I wanted to know if there is any way in which to remove this popup advertisement permanently from my website, while still having it hosted freely, so that I can complete the Data Highlighting of the website using Google Webmaster Tools.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Google Webmaster Tools do not render ads on your side. What ist the "Data Highlihting Section"? Show us the ink or the code, please

Comment: @AxelAmthor I'm referring to the Data Highlighter in Google Webmaster Tools under Search Appearance. My website is rendered with a popup advertisement by Hostinger. Therefor I cannot highlight the data on my website. Please help. Thanks.